# Save reference to other collection

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

How do you save a reference to another collection within Firebase Firestore? The [docs on adding data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) doesn't mention anything about saving references.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Firestore supports storing of a reference to a document ([`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference)) rather than to a collection, but you can add a `DocumentReference` to the database just like any other [supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), something like this in JavaScript:

```javascript
db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
    name: "Los Angeles",
    state: db.collection("states").doc("CA"),
    country: "USA",
});
```

Comment: Just for those looking for clarification, you do need to use `.ref` to be able to store the data correctly. In this specific case you would need: `state: db.collection('states').doc('CA').ref,`

Comment: @AmitBravo No, think of it more as a [pointer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)), so you will need to read the value of the other document.

Comment: yeah, I knew it later today and we can access it something like 
db.collection("cities").doc("LA").get()
.then(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
         console.log("Document data:", doc.data().state.get);
          doc.data().state.get()
           .then(data2 => {
              console.log('data2',data2.data())
           })
     } 
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});